# Name of a distro

Tags: linux, history, distributions

Recently I've been trying to remember the name of the first distro I ever used, and no searching has turned up anything yet. I even found a distro 'family tree' that covered the period but I didn't see anything that rang any bells. I suspect it starts with a 'c' or a 'p' but I'm likely wrong, though I'm pretty sure it ended with an 'x'.

The mascot/logo on the front was of a green circular character, dressed up like a Roman Centurion, and I believe the CD case cover, one of the double-width jewel case styles, was a dark red colour.

This was a distro that came on a 2-3 CDs somewhere around '96-'98... It was definitely pre 2.4, and possibly pre 2.2.I know it was release before BeOS R5 Pro (released 2000).

Comment: See https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Linux_Distribution_Timeline.svg for a overview of distributions

Comment: While this is about interesting Linux trivia, we can't really know what you had back '96 or '97, so this is rather off-topic. Such a nice OT though, that I'm not going to flag it :)

Comment: @Lambert, that's the 'family tree' I mentioned. The fact that I can't find it on there is what's making me so intrigued.

Comment: Was this the CD?  https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CNND6BSU8AA7bfg.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CD set you're thinking of were the "Infomagic Linux Developer CDs".

Infomagic was a company that sold many different CD sets (BSD, Linux, DOS, etc).  The Linux ones typically had 4 or more disks and would contain a few distributions (eg Debian, RedHat, Slackware) plus a lot of source code include XFree86 and so on.

There were two variations for Linux that had the "red" background.  There was a 5 CD set with [image: 5cd image]

There was also a 6 CD set with [image: a very similar image]

I installed RedHat 4.1 back in the mid 90s from an Infomagic set :-)

Comment: Oh, nostalgia flashback!